# How does accusing work? What kind of anonymous operation is sent to the network?

Tags: baking, accuser

Could anyone tell some more details about this, more than the summary information found on StackExchange and the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Accusing work by submitting evidence that two endorsements (or two blocks) were signed at the same height, by the same key, but referred to a different block hash (had a different) block hash. Any miner can include such an accusation in their block and receive a reward for it.

See `double_endorsement_evidence` and `double_baking_evidence` in

http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/api/p2p.html#operation-alpha-specific